# Transitioning child's CSS property

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have following piece of CSS code:

```
#balancers div p {      
  display: none;
}

#balancers div:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

And markup:

```
<div id="balancers">
  <h1>ID</h1>
  <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

It works as expected - when I hover over `<div>` element, it'll show `<p>` element. However, I'd like to use CSS transitions here (make `<div>` slowly increase it's height, without manipulating `height` property).

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto

Answer (score 1):

I made an example: [CSS3 Transition Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pQn52/9/)

It is possible without JS.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to create this sort of animation with basic CSS. You would need to use something like jQuery animate to get this effect:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$("div#balancers").hover(function(){
    $("div#balancers p").show();
    $("div#balancers p").animate({
        height:"200px"
    }, 1500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use jQuery to achieve something like what your asking.

```
$("#balancers p").hover(function(){ 
   $(this).fadeOut(100);
   $(this).fadeIn(500);}
);
```

Ex: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score -2):

Your CSS markup is wrong. Correct would be:

```
div#balancers > p {      
  display: none;
}

div#balancers:hover > p {
  display: block;
}


<div id="balancers">
  <h1>ID</h1>
  <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope. In fact, It's advised not to specify the element tripe with ids and classes in css. It makes it ineficiente without need, since ids are supossed to be uniq.